# DB2 Convert ISO 8601 timestamp string to DB2 timestamp

Tags: sql, db2

I have a requirement where I get two strings in ISO 8601 Timestamp format and I have to compare them and get the max timestamp of them. The strings are in the following format.

```
2014-06-11T16:45:45Z
```

To compare, I need to cast them into DB2 timestamp and then compare. The problem is with the "T" and "Z" letters. Because of that, I am unable to cast. I know that I can simply  `REPLACE` the T and Z and cast, but I wanted to know if there is a better way.

I tried the following functions but was not able to get the desired results.

```
to_date, to_timestamp, varchar_format, cast as
```

Using DB2 LUW v9.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the good news: your values are SARGable, that is simply comparing them *as strings* will return the correct results (`MAX(...)` will work as needed).  This won't help with the casting, but at least it'd still spit out the "greater" value.

For casting, there's a couple of things you could do here.

First, so long as your date/time portions remain in that format, it's probably easier to grab them separately and recombine for the timestamp:

```
TIMESTAMP(SUBSTR(@inputParm, 1, 10), SUBSTR(@inputParm, 12, 8)) AS resultTimestamp
```

LUW also has a function called [TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html) (`TO_TIMESTAMP` is technically a synonym for this).  I'm assuming that the system is actually choking on the fact that you don't have fractional seconds in your incoming data.  I'd recommend trying something like this:

```
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS ', @inputParm)
```

The better option, however, may be to get whoever's calling your db to pass in a parameter typed as a `timestamp` instead of as a `string` - this means you wouldn't have to do any conversion workarounds at all.

Comment: `Sargable` is good enough for me. If I can compare directly without the need of casting, its just perfect. Thanks for pointing that out.

The `TO_TIMESTAMP` function isn't very helpful because it adds a **.0** microsecond extra in the end (which is not a problem when comparing, but it is when am casting it back to the original input ISO 8601 format). 

About the last suggestion, nobody is calling our DB. We are reading the date from an input XML and that cannot be altered as there are other systems that accept this format as well.

Comment: For dealing with the result when you are casting back to string in the end, _that's_ when you'd use [`VARCHAR_FORMAT(...)`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html) (unfortunately I don't think it'll put `'T'` or `'Z'` back in, but you could try).  Are you actually storing timestamps as strings?  That might give you problems later...

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that my values are `Sargable` (as mentioned by **Clockwork-Muse**), I still went ahead and wrote code to **Unbox** (ISO 8601 String to Timestamp) and **Box** (Timestamp to ISO 8601 String) the values. Once unboxed, I compared them and once I got the max value, I boxed it.

**Unboxing** (Used `REPLACE` and `TO_TIMESTAMP` function):

```
SELECT 
   TO_TIMESTAMP(REPLACE(REPLACE('2014-04-14T15:19:45Z','T',' '),'Z',''),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

**Boxing** (Unboxing appends an extra **.0** microseconds, so replacing it as well)

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE('2014-04-14 15:19:45.0',' ','T'),'.0','Z')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```