# dashDB: how to create a TIMESTAMP from an ISO 8601 date?

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

I have a VARCHAR field storing an iso 8601 date as follows: `2015-01-13T23:17:00`

I would like to convert the date into a TIMESTAMP.

It seems that I have to strip out the 'T' to use the `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` function:

```
SELECT
    T.F1,
    T.F2,
    TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(
        REPLACE(T."log_date", 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
    ) TS
FROM
   "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" T
```

This feels a bit clumsy.  What is the recommended way of parsing ISO 8601 dates in dashDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the approach I taken in dashDB although a bit kludgey but is similar to what others have recommended for DB2.  See some answers for DB2, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161528/db2-convert-iso-8601-timestamp-string-to-db2-timestamp).